# Is it safe to set WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS for all platforms/compilers?

Tags: windows, cmake, buildconfiguration, symbol-visibility

I'm building a C or C++ library, and I want to arrange it so that all symbols defined in my objects to be exported by default. I know can do this with the [WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html) target property; but - I want to know whether it's safe to just always set this property to `ON`, or whether that will break things (e.g. on other platforms or with other compilers).

Note: I don't mind if it doesn't do anything on another platform, I just want to avoid having to check a bunch of conditions before I set it.